# Can't find any way to click on the dropdown menu to choose any preferable item

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, click

I've written some code in vba using IE to choose `England Premier League` from a dropdown which is visible as `Next To Play` at this moment. My target is to click on that dropdown link captioned as `Next To Play` and then choose the `Australia A-League` from option. However, I can't find any way to click on that very link. If I run my below script the way it is, it neither works nor throws any error and finally quits the browser.

Link to that webpage: [URL](https://ubet.com/sports/soccer/nexttoplay)

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub soccer()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "replace_with_above_link"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    For Each post In html.getElementsByTagName("option")
''        If InStr(post.innerText, "Next To Play") > 0 Then MsgBox post.innerText: Exit For  ''checked to see if I'm on the right place
        If InStr(post.innerText, "Next To Play") > 0 Then post.Click: Exit For
    Next post

   IE.Quit
End Sub
```

This is the partial picture of the webpage where I wanna trigger a click.

[image]

I would like to be able to click on that link and choose any option from there.

It seems I'm close to the solution. My below script can select the portion I wanna perform a click:

```
Sub Soccer_Dropdown()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://ubet.com/sports/soccer/nexttoplay"
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Set post = html.querySelector(".ubet-fixed-price-navigator-selector-league select")
    post.Focus

'   IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Picture of the result:

[image]

However, when it comes to perform a click I can't do anymore.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant [vba-to-change-dropdown-value-in-internet-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741188/vba-to-change-dropdown-value-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Thanks QHarr for your suggestion. The solution you talk about is a working one and it does work here as well. I've tested it. However, the thing is I expect to learn about how clicking method works in IE. Moreover, this type of solution breaks most of the cases. I have come across lots of webpages in which, even if the value of something is made to change within that page the url stays the same. Thanks again for the link.

Comment: I will be watching as keen to see how this is resolved. I had a play for a while and still wasn't able to get the follow through on the link but i am not that familiar with HTML manipulation via VBA.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out to me.  I was going to say that you go straight for the HTML manipulation, but most sites have protection against over writing, unless its server side, that is how hacking happens.

Comment: Have you seen this: [How to fire listbox's ONCHANGE event programmatically](https://forums.asp.net/t/1470345.aspx?How+to+fire+listbox+s+ONCHANGE+event+programmatically)?

Comment: No I haven't yet. Gonna track this link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does GUI web-browser is absolutely required for webscraping ? Let me doubt...

If you try to debug the [target page](https://ubet.com/sports/soccer/nexttoplay) you will see that the data you are looking for is JSON type and is resulting from an XHR request.

So assuming that you got all required cookies to sent an XHR request to the target website, you may directly get the JSON data (from curl) instead of browsing the website ...

---

Apparently each league have an unique ID (50 for england, 76 for Australia, etc...)

So in order to get access to the `Australia A-League` data , you have to send a GET request :

https://ubet.com/api/sportsViewData/nexttoplay/false/3/76 `Australia A-League`

---

In this resulting JSON file, you will get an `Offers` key, which contain a dict which contain all offers and contain also all required data I expect that you  are looking to  scrap....

Please see an offer example :

```
LongDisplayName "Central Coast Mariners"
DisplayOrder    1
OfferOrder  1
HAD 1
PlaceDeduction  0
ShowOfferBasedDynamicOffer  false
OfferId 308151
OfferName   "Central Coast"
DisplayHAD  1
WinReturn   1.85
PlaceReturn 0
DynamicOffer    null
Status  "o"
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks A STEFANI, for your offer. Basically, I'm not interested in their data at all. I can simply do that using selenium in combination with vba or python. In fact, to reach the data it is not necessary to initiate a click. If i scrape the league names and concatenate each league with the base url then I can reach the data. All I wanna learn is how to perform a click using IE and select any item from the dropdown option. That's it.

Comment: For click issue, did you try "mousedown" then "mouseup" event instead of the "click" event ?

Comment: Thanks @A STEFANI for shedding some light. No, I didn't try that. I'm not familiar with that. Could you please guide me on that.

Answer (score 1):

Navigating to `https://ubet.com/sports/soccer/england-premier-league` gets you that web page.

I know that is a short answer.  I have been looking at this for some time (even though the answer is brief) and it is an Angular.js application but I cannot yet figure out how it works.  Somehow one needs to call `vm.selectedKeyChange` manually.  I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is do-able as a small extension of your existing code.

I avoid using `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` because they are flakey (per your other bounty [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993064/my-scraper-throws-errors-instead-of-quitting-the-browser-when-everything-is-done)).

I didn't use `Focus` and used `Click` instead as I'm guessing this executes whatever required script runs in the background.

You can then either manually select the correct index (using `selectedIndex`) or search the child elements for the `<label>` value you need:

Working code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Soccer_Dropdown()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim divElement As Object, selectElement As Object, optionElement As Object
    Dim optionIndex As Long
    Dim targetOption  As String

    ' load page
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://ubet.com/sports/soccer/nexttoplay"
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    ' let page do its thing
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    ' get the div
    Set divElement = html.getElementsByClassName("ubet-fixed-price-navigator-selector-league")

    ' get the select in the div
    Set selectElement = divElement(0).getElementsByTagName("select")(0)

    ' click it to activate any script to populate select
    selectElement.Click

    ' select by index - this works but showing the other technique below
    'selectElement.selectedIndex = 9

    ' select by iterating the options
    optionIndex = 0
    targetOption = "Australia A-League"
    For Each optionElement In selectElement
        If LCase(optionElement.localName) = "option" And optionElement.Label = targetOption Then
            selectElement.selectedIndex = optionIndex
            Debug.Print targetOption & " at index " & optionIndex
            Exit For
        End If
        optionIndex = optionIndex + 1
    Next

    ' quit IE
    'IE.Quit

End Sub
```

### Edit

@QHarr - per your question *How does Set selectElement = divElement(0).getElementsByTagName("select")(0) access the "Australia A-League"?*

The div containing the dropdown has class `ubet-fixed-price-navigator-selector-league` and that `<div>` has a single `<select>` element - which is the dropdown. Because `getElementsByTagName` returns a set of HTML elements, we are just saying to return the *first* `<select>` element within the `<div>`. The 0 index doesn't refer to the list of things in the dropdown (i.e. the `<option>`s). See the HTML:

[image]

A bit further down the HTML you can see the `<option>` elements (grouped in `<optgroup>`s) where you can access the dropdown values:

[image]

@Topto - good question - the `localName` property, along with a few others for the `optionElement` variable was one that I could see in the Locals window as having a value of `option`:

[image]

I guess you could use `nodeName` just as well as `localName`. There is `tagName` as well, which I suppose is the most obvious sounding:

[image]

HTH

Comment: You are the vba giant @Robin Mackenzie. You just made me dumbfounded with your revolutionary script. Thankssssssssssssssss a trillion.

Comment: How does  Set selectElement = divElement(0).getElementsByTagName("select")(0)  access the "Australia A-League"  please? I can't test on this machine but it "feels" like it should be accessing the UK section?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie, a simple question to get the clarity on one thing: in your script you used `optionElement.localName` within the for loop. Firstly I thought `.localName` was an attribute taken from the elements from that webpage but I suppose I'm wrong. What is it actually? Thanks again.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Thank you very much. I had been monitoring this question for the solutions given. Very helpful for stuff i am looking at at present. Much obliged for the extra detail.

Comment: You are just impossible @RobinMackenzie. You made my day.